# Push new object to nested mongodb document where particular condition matches within a sub document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am new to Nodejs and Mongodb. I am building Message Chat Functionality in my project. I have done with Message Schema.

This is my User Model Schema:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name : {
       type     : String
    },
    email : {
       type : String
   },
   password : {
       type     : String
   },
   chats : [{
        chatId : String,
        messages : [{
            type  : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref   : 'Message'
        }]
    }]  
});
```

I want to add all the new message objects to the subdocument where chatId is matched. So,that I can easily use it on front end (which is Angular) with structured
I have tried this:

```
var msg = new Message({
    senderId : req.user._id,
    to       : toUser,
    from     : user,
    message  : req.body.msg,
    datetime : new Date()
})

msg.save();

const chatFr = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { 'chats.chatId' :  req.user._id },
        { $push : { 'chats' : msg  }}
)
```

It is creating a separate object.I don't know how to use 'where' in sub-documents here. I am coming from Sql background. Please help how to execute conditional queries in sub documents in mongodb/mongoose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
await User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { 'chats.chatId' :  req.user._id },
  { $addToSet: { 'chats.$.messages' : msg  }}}
)
```

You need to insert using the [$ position operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/index.html). You can also utilize [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/).

Comment: Woww. thank you much It worked with '$' position operator. I will read about $addtoSet operator also... Thanks again :)